# Uploading zip file. When downloading, it's corrupt

Tags: c#, zip

I'm uploading a zip file to Bugzilla with the following code:

```
bug.AppendAttachment("someComment", "application/octet-stream", "somedata",
"filePath", bugId, false, false, false, "someSummary");
```

The false parameters are:
1. is_Url
2. is_patch
3. is_private

The file is uploaded, and when I login to Bugzilla and download id, a message appears which says it's corrupted or damaged and cannot be opened. Why is this happening? When I'm uploading it by hand, everything is ok.

Comment: What exactly is "somedata" here? Is it meant to be the contents of the zip file? Because zip files are binary content...

Comment: Please provide a link to the API you're using.  The closest I could find is http://oss.dbc.dk/bugzproxy/html/index.html, which doesn't have an `AppendAttachment` method.

Comment: @ziesemer Yes, I;m using bugzproxy, and added a method for adding an attachment: http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#add_attachment

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmm I thought it was just a string.

Comment: @Srcee: It says it's base64... have you base-64-encoded the data? Basically you haven't shown us how you're getting the *real* data, as "somedata" obviously isn't a zip file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to see your addition of `AppendAttachment` to further answer this.  However, per http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#add_attachment, you need to ensure that whatever you're passing to "data" is properly [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded.

If `somedata` is what you are directly passing to `data`, you need to first encode your binary data (the Zip file) to Base64 using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx.

If you attempt to store your binary data as a String at any point before encoding it with Base64, you will corrupt your payload.