# How to upload zip file through S3 signed URL

Tags: python, amazon-s3, upload, client-server, postman

I am getting a signed URL from S3 and then tried a file upload using POSTMAN

File is getting uploaded but not full data as the result file is getting corrupted.

When I tried to do it via python requests module as

```
    f= open("windows.zip")
    d = f.read()
    req = requests.put(s3URL, data=d)
```

The results are same.

But When I do

```
    f = open("window.zip", "rb")
    d = f.read()
    req = requests.put(s3URL, data=d)
```

It works fine. Whole file get uploaded.

So any ideas do it via POSTMAN or without reading the file in binary mode.

because I don't have option to tell the client side that open your file binary mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So When you open a file in Binary mode, you dont need any encoding.
But on other hand direct upload needs a base64 encoding

[refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278496/uploading-zip-file-when-downloading-its-corrupt?rq=1)

Comment: Okay this works at my end. But Now i need to tell client side to encode there data. Now I am looking for more server side solution for this if there is any